# Spring Data 'Left Join Fetch' query returning null

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

My query looks like this:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Pilot p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.playerShips WHERE p.nickname = (:nickname)")
```

So far so good. I'm getting Pilot instance even when playerShips is empty.
Now, I want to fetch only inactive ships so I modified my query to look like this:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Pilot p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.playerShips s WHERE p.nickname = (:nickname) AND s.active = false")
```

and I'm getting null as a pilot so it clearly doesn't work. 
I'd be glad if someone could explain me how to create a JOIN FETCH query with WHERE clause that applies to the child elements. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your table structure

Comment: playerShips table contains 'active' column which is boolean and foreign key column 'pilot_id' which refers to Pilot.ID and that's the important stuff.

Comment: It is not a good idea to selectively retrieve only part of the ~ToMany relationship.  You are going to face a lot of problem.  Do the filtering in code instead.  Unless you want to totally ignore all inactive ship in your whole application (which is what your answer is doing).

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on your comment? Right now with my answer I am calling findByNicknameFetchInactiveShips and it fetches only inactive ships so they are not ignored at all. Also, what problems retrieving only part of the ToMany may cause? Moreover, there was an error "with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters" when I used pure jpql so there must be a reason for the "use filters" which is what I am doing now. I always have room for improvement so I'd like to hear more about it. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of research, I decided to implement a custom repository so that I can use Hibernate Filters and now it works.

**PilotRepository:**

```
@Repository
public interface PilotRepository extends JpaRepository<Pilot, Long>, PilotRepositoryCustom{
/*spring data methods here*/
}
```

**PilotRepositoryCustom:**

```
public interface PilotRepositoryCustom {
    public Pilot findByNicknameFetchInactiveShips(String nickname);
}
```

**PilotRepositoryImpl:**

```
public class PilotRepositoryImpl implements PilotRepositoryCustom{

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Pilot findByNicknameFetchInactiveShips(String nickname) {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.enableFilter("active").setParameter("active", false);
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
                "SELECT p FROM Pilot p " +
                "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.playerShips ps " +
                "LEFT JOIN FETCH ps.ship s " +
                "WHERE p.nickname = (:nickname)");
        query.setParameter("nickname", nickname);
        return (Pilot)query.getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

That's it about spring data. Now the Filters configuration:
**Pilot Entity:**

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pilot")
    @Filter(name="active", condition = "active = :active")
    private List<PlayerShip> playerShips;
```

**PlayerShip Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="player_ship")
@FilterDef(name="active", parameters=@ParamDef(name="active",type="java.lang.Boolean"))
public class PlayerShip {
    /*...*/
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pilot_id")
    private Pilot pilot;
    /*...*/
}
```

**IMPORTANT :**
If you use Boolean in @ParamDef, make sure to type **java.lang.Boolean** instead of just **Boolean**. I've spent more than one hour wondering why I keep getting **parameter not found/not defined error**.

Answer (score 3):

Just move it to the join condition:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Pilot p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.playerShips s ON s.active = false WHERE p.nickname = (:nickname)")
```

The ON clause is defined in the JPA 2.1

Comment: Tried it. Throws the following error: with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters. I'm looking for filters now but I don't think it's possible to use them with Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Try this one or native query: `SELECT p FROM Pilot p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.playerShips s WHERE p.nickname = (:nickname) AND (s is null OR s.active = false)`