# Spring data jpa left join fetch and where clause

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following query in my repository:

```
SELECT p FROM Project p JOIN p.users u WHERE u.login =:login
```

There is a Many To Many relationshio between user and project.
Everything works fine and it returns the user's projects, but I want it for each project to return the corresponding set of users.

UPDATE: Tried the following as mateuszlo suggested:

```
SELECT p FROM Project p JOIN FECTH p.users JOIN p.users u WHERE u.login =:login
```

But now i got the following exception:

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Count query validation failed for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.app.repository.ProjectRepository.findAllByUserLo‌​gin(java.lang.String‌​,org.springframework‌​.data.domain.Pageabl‌​e)! org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
```

Comment: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27369964/3641067)

Answer (score 5):

It is impossible to create a named alias for a FETCH JOIN query to use it in a `WHERE` statement. JPA doesn't allow this on purpose, because it could easly lead to unwanted situations.

Consider a `Project` X, which has 3 `Users`: John, Tom and Mike. Query with FETCH JOIN for projects, that have user John would return `Project` X with only one `User` - John. That would produce an incomplete `Project` entity, which is inconsistent with current database state.

So what you have to do is to join twice. First time with normal `JOIN`, to identify proper `Projet` records, and then second time with `FETCH JOIN` to fetch correspoding `Users`:

```
SELECT p FROM Project p 
JOIN FETCH p.users
JOIN p.users u WHERE u.login =:login
```

Comment: Thanks mateuszlo. Already tried it but got the following exception:  nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Count query validation failed for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.app.repository.ProjectRepository.findAllByUserLogin(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list

Answer (score 0):

First off I'm assuming you're using pagination? That is you have a Pagable parameter on your JPA query method? If so, there are two ways to solve this.

#### Count query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT p FROM Project p " +
       "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.users u WHERE u.login = :login",
countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(u) FROM User u WHERE u.login = :login")
Page<Project> fetchProjectsByUserLogin(String login, Pageable pageable);
```

#### Entity Graph

```
@Query(value = "SELECT p FROM Project p " +
       "LEFT JOIN p.users u WHERE u.login = :login")
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"users"}, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)
Page<Project> fetchProjectsByUserLogin(String login, Pageable pageable);
```